# How to access dictionary within the list of dictionaries element in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the a dictionary whose values are a list of dictionary. For example -

```
dj={'101': [{'Name': 'vamc'}, {'House': 'yes'}, {'married': 'yes'}, {'car': '1'}], '102': [{'Name': 'suresh'}, {'House': 'no'}, {'married': 'yes'}, {'car': '0'}]}
```

I would like to access the car attribute of the id = '102'. I tried something like this to solve my problem.

```
li=[]
dj={}

def indec():
    di1={}
    di2={}
    di3={}
    di4={}
    di1['Name']=input("Enter the Name")
    di2['House']=input("Enter the House status")
    di3['married']=input("Enter the married status")
    di4['car']=input("Enter no of cars")
    li=[di1,di2,di3,di4]
    return li


x=int(input("Enter How many values:"))
for i in range(x):
    y=input("Enter id")
    dj[y]=indec()

id=input("Enter the id whose no of cars do u want:")
print("No of cars are:",dj[id['car']])
```

Any simpler solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard about our lord and savior, the object oriented programming ?

Comment: Added an OOP example @MaximGi

Comment: Hi, Check if my answer helped you in your question? @SureshReshu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
to_search = 'car'
index = '102'

dj={'101': [{'Name': 'vamc'}, {'House': 'yes'}, {'married': 'yes'}, {'car': '1'}], '102': [{'Name': 'suresh'}, {'House': 'no'}, {'married': 'yes'}, {'car': '0'}]}

result_list = [ val for val in dj[index] if to_search in val ]

print result_list[0]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would as @MaximGi mentioned using OOP. That would make your life easier.

But if you insist on solving this problem without OOP, you can convert the list of dictionaries into a single dictionary as it's an attribute of single person.

```
def convert_to_single_record(attributes):
    record = {}
    for attribute in attributes:
        record.update(attribute)
    return record

customer_record = {'101': [{'Name': 'vamc'},
                           {'House': 'yes'},
                           {'married': 'yes'},
                           {'car': '1'}],
                   '102': [{'Name': 'suresh'},
                           {'House': 'no'},
                           {'married': 'yes'},
                           {'car': '0'}]}

records = {}
for id, attributes in customer_record.items():
    records[id] = convert_to_single_record(attributes)

print(records['102']['car'])
```

Comment: What is the variable 'customer_record' assigned to ?

Answer (score 1):

An Object Oriented approach as mentioned by @MaximGi

```
#Class to encapsulate person
class Person:

  def __init__(self, id, name, house, married, car):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.house = house
    self.married = married
    self.car = car


li=[]

#Get input values from user
def indec():

    name=input("Enter the Name")
    house=input("Enter the House status")
    married=input("Enter the married status")
    car=input("Enter no of cars")
    return name, house, married, car

#In a for loop, create a person object and append it to list
x=int(input("Enter How many values:"))
for i in range(x):
    y=input("Enter id")
    p = Person(y, *indec())
    li.append(p)


id=input("Enter the id whose no of cars do u want:")
#Loop through person list and print car attribute for which the id matches
for p in li:
  if p.id == id:
    print("No of cars are:",p.car)
```

The output comes out as

```
Enter How many values:2
Enter id101
Enter the Namevamc
Enter the House statusyes
Enter the married statusyes
Enter no of cars1
Enter id102
Enter the Namesuresh
Enter the House statusyes
Enter the married statusno
Enter no of cars0
Enter the id whose no of cars do u want:102
No of cars are: 0
```